# React js in AEM

Tags: reactjs, aem

I am using react js in Adobe experience manager (AEM) I am getting console errors. Here is my code: I am getting

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

also I am getting error near

> '<' "Unexpected token error"

Can someone please help?

```
import React from "react";

import {Header} from "./Header";

export class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <Header />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: are you minifying your code through the YUI compressor that ships with AEM? I've had bad experiences in the past with this.

Comment: Your first error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" suggests that react.js is not compiling the jsx properly. Also, the second error suggests that something like a minifier is trying to process jsx.

Comment: Can you add some detail concerning where in your code base this code is how it gets to the resultant site, and where/when you are actually getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS is not supported on AEM, and is not recommended by Adobe.

Having said that, there are some resources on aem-react, see if these can help:

- Vimeo recording:   Ben Westrate - ICFI - React.js in AEM on Vimeo
  https://vimeo.com/139968905
- https://github.com/sinnerschrader/aem-react
- https://github.com/sinnerschrader/aem-react-js
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/aem-react-js

Answer (score 1):

We were able to use react components by always including a webpack config file with every component.
Every react component then gets transpiled to es5 in our build pipeline.
AEM Clientlibs compile with the transpiled javascripts on render.

Comment: Can you share an example component?

Comment: I am not sure how the webpack.config.js file is built to have the react component file built.  I can  one big bundle.js is produced :
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [react-from-markup](https://github.com/simon360/react-from-markup) where you can declare React components using simple, static markup.

For example, this code:

```html
<div data-react-from-markup-container>
  <p class="hello-world">Hello, world!</p>
</div>
```

becomes:

```javascript
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement("p", { className: "hello-world" }, "Hello, world!"),
  container
);
```

Docs: https://simon360.github.io/react-from-markup